# Подстроки повторяющихся символов фиксированной длины

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

В логах строки вида `XXXXxxxYYyyyyZZZZzzW`, т.е. ряд повторяющихся символов в разном регистре. Нужно регуляркой захватить из каждого набора повторов подстроки фиксированной длины: было `XXXXxxxYYyyyyZZZZzzW` и стало `['XXX', 'YYy', 'ZZZ', 'W']`. Иначе говоря, если символов больше — убрать лишние, в протвном случае оставить как есть. Знаний регулярок хвалило лишь на `/(.)\1{2}|\S/gi`, но match захватывает много лишнего. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть в данном случае, что исправить? В смысле, чтобы было решено всё регуляркой именно, а не через reduce, map и прочее?

Comment: [Вариант с негативным просмотром вперед](https://regex101.com/r/DkpPtX/1)

Comment: не знаю, все равно ли автору, но захватываются последние буквы

Comment: Алексей Р, спасибо, буду разбираться. Так как регистр не имеет значения, можете вынести в решение?

Comment: Разве это решение? Результат-то другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с негативным просмотром вперед. Особенность: выражение захватывает до трех последних символов в серии.

```
/(.)\1{0,2}(?!\1)/gmi
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/DkpPtX/1)